# Prevent value in bloc from resetting

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have 2 screens, 1 product screen and 1 cart screen. The product screen just displays all the product and when the user clicks add to cart, it will fire the AddToCart event. The problem is I keep getting 'Cart is empty.' and the cart variable in *cart bloc* keeps resetting to [] when i switch back and forth the product and cart screen.

**Main screen**

```
MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<ProductBloc>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => ProductBloc()..add(FetchProduct()),
      ),
      BlocProvider<CartBloc>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => CartBloc()..add(FetchCart()),
      ),
    ],
)
```

**Cart State**

```
abstract class CartState extends Equatable {
  const CartState();
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
class CartInitial extends CartState {}
class CartLoading extends CartState {}
class CartSuccess extends CartState {
  final List<ProductModel> carts;
  const CartSuccess(this.carts);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [carts];
}
class CartFailed extends CartState {}
```

**Cart Event**

```
abstract class CartEvent extends Equatable {
  const CartEvent();
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
class FetchCart extends CartEvent {}
class AddToCart extends CartEvent {
  final ProductModel product;
  const AddToCart(this.product);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [product];
}
class RemoveFromCart extends CartEvent {
  final ProductModel product;
  const RemoveFromCart(this.product);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [product];
}
```

**Cart Bloc**

```
class CartBloc extends Bloc<CartEvent, CartState> {
  CartBloc() : super(CartInitial());

  List<ProductModel> carts = []; // always resets

  Stream<CartState> mapEventToState(CartEvent event) async* {

    print(carts);

    if(event is FetchCart){
        yield CartSuccess(carts);
        print(carts.length);
    }

    if(event is AddToCart){
      try{
        carts.add(event.product);
        yield CartSuccess(carts);
        print(carts.length);
      }catch(e){
        yield CartFailed();
        print(e);
      }
    }

    if(event is RemoveFromCart){
      try{
        carts.remove(event.product);
        yield CartSuccess(carts);
      }catch(e){
        yield CartFailed();
        print(e);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

**Cart Screen**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: BlocBuilder<CartBloc, CartState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if(state is CartInitial){
              print('CartInitial');
              return buildLoadingWidget();
            }
            if(state is CartSuccess){
              print('CartSuccess');
              if(state.carts.length == 0)
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Cart is empty.',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)
                ));
              else
                return _buildProductListWidget(state.carts);
            }
            if(state is CartFailed){
              print('CartFailed');
              return Center(
                child: Text('Something went wrong'),
              );
            }
            return buildLoadingWidget();
          }
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the main screen's build method is getting called and new Instance of the blocs are being created inside the providers. Better use a variable for those Blocs, like instead of `ProductBloc()..add(FetchProduct()),`
Use a variable,

```
final productBloc = ProductBloc();

initState(){
   productBloc.add(FetchProduct());
}

//Then in the provider,
MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<ProductBloc>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => productBloc,
      ),
      
    ],
)
```

In this way, it will not create new blocs, instead it will use the same one created and stored in the variable.

Comment: Code like that is not a good idea, because if previous bloc disposed it will dispose `productBloc` instance as well. Then new `BlockProvider` will be created with an invalid bloc instance.

Comment: I know, the user can dispose the bloc by overwriting dispose method or you must use a stateless widget in that case so that the build method doesn't get called again. or while navigating use the `maintainState: true` if that helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code is OK and the problem somewhere else. Perhaps you recreate bloc on every page switch or something. You can add a print statement to `CartBloc` constructor and then switch the page and look into the console for those statements. So you can try to find the wrong place in such a way. Or you can update the post with more code, so someone will be able to figure out what's wrong with it. Also you can try to move your `MultiBlocProvider` higher in the widget hierarchy, if recreation is the problem then it should help.